# cypress wait for intercept never gets triggered

Tags: cypress

I register an interceptor:

```
cy.intercept("/api/v1/payments/customers/payment_methods.json*").as('payment_methods')
```

and then make an action that triggers this request:

```
GET 200 /api/v1/payments/customers/payment_methods.json?some-query-params-here
```

then wait for it

```
cy.wait("@payment_methods");
```

and even tho I can see the get request after the wait has been registered, the wait times out:

[image]

any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: If I call your exact intercept  and trigger your exact fetch, it works. Do you have other intercepts in the test?

Comment: Try calling first the cy.wait and then the GET 200 api

Comment: don't have any other intercepts @TesterDick but we're running cypress 7 and maybe this was fixed on 9, so will check that

Answer (score 0):

Try using cy.intercept() with RouteMathcer, like `cy.intercept({ method: 'GET', pathname: '/api/v1/payments/customers/payment_methods.json' }).as('payment_methods')`. As stated in docs pathname is used as a HTTP request path, but without query parameters.